# How to correctly create a POST method for nested serializers in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializerclass which is like this:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bio = BioSerializer()
    # designation = GroupListSerializer()
    # department = GroupListSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['user','bio','tax_id_number','account_number','joining_date','designation','department']
```

How do I make a `POST` method for this in django correctly:

So far this is what I have:

```
class EmployeeCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EmployeeSerializer


    def post(self, request, format=None):

        designation = Group.objects.get(id=request.data['designation'],)
        department = Group.objects.get(id=request.data['department'],)
        user =User.objects.get(id=request.data['user'],)
        bio =Bio.objects.get(id=request.data['bio'],)


        # user=User.objects.get(id=request.data['user'],)    
        employee = Employee.objects.create(
            tax_id_number=request.data['tax_id_number'],
            account_number=request.data['account_number'],
            joining_date=request.data['joining_date'],
            designation =designation,
            department =department,
            user=user,
            bio=bio,

            )

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATE
```

D)

But when i make a post request I get the following in my logs:

```
 MultiValueDictKeyError at /hr/employee_create/
"'bio'"
```

Comment: Can you show the POST payload ? also add `BioSerializer()`\

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the serializer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to override the `create()` in your `views.py`. Use only this, and override serializers' `create()` method if you want (I think that's the good strategy for DRF)

```
class EmployeeCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EmployeeSerializer
```

request payload

```
{
    "user": "user data",
    "tax_id_number": 12344,
    "bio": {
        "field1": "foo",
        "field2": "bar"
    },
    "other fields": "values"

}
```